# External font family are not loading in my HTML website

Tags: html, css, font-family

I am trying to apply custom fonts on my web page, but some fonts are not applying. Can anyone help me, please?

```
CSS

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CircularStd-Book';
    src: url('fonts/CircularStd-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
}

h1,h2{
    font-family: 'CircularStd-Book';
}
```

[This is the path marked in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Yuz.png)

Above mention font family I'm using to call and I have mentioned the right path to the font but it's not working

Comment: Open the console and see if you got any 404 errors for font file not found.

Comment: Are you sure about the path 'fonts/CircularStd-Book.ttf' ? I suggest you to check it again.

Comment: yeah, the path is right and not getting any 404 errors

Comment: your css code is correct. something must be wrong with the path of the font or the font file.

Comment: You should also specify the font-weight. By default headings `h1` and `h2` will have a font-weight: bold. So add e.g  `font-weight:normal` to your `@font-face` rule as well as your h1,h2 style

Comment: calling the right path but not working. Please, anyone, help me with this.